# Kotlin generic functions and contravariance

Tags: kotlin, generics, contravariance

I cannot get my head around a seemingly easy problem. I have `Reply` class, which can contain different response types - `Views`:

```
interface View
data class NiceView(val name: String) : View

class MyReply<T : View>(view: T)
```

Now, I'd like to write a function that accepts a command and returns an appropriate view based on the command:

```
fun <T : View> handle(command: Command): Reply<T> {
   return Reply(NiceView(""))
}
```

I can see two issues here:

1. I get this weird error on the return type `Reply<T>`, but this only happens in this toy example and not my production code:

   ```
   Type argument is not within its bounds.
   Expected: View
   Found: T
   ```
2. Error when returning `Reply()`. This is the thing that is killing my brain and this is what I'm seeing in my production code:

   ```
   Type mismatch.
   Required: T
   Found: NiceView
   Type mismatch.
   Required: Reply<T>
   Found: Reply<NiceView>
   Type mismatch.
   Required: View
   Found: NiceView
   ```

I did try messing around with co- and contravariance using `in` and `out` keywords but to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: If you have time, this is a great series of posts: https://typealias.com/guides/illustrated-guide-covariance-contravariance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fun <T : View> handle(command: Command): Reply<T> {` does *not* mean a function that "accepts a command and returns an appropriate view."  It means "a function that accepts a type of view -- and a command -- and returns a reply of that type of view."  The *caller* of `handle` can choose whatever type of `View` it wants to get, which is not what you want -- nor what you've implemented, since the user might want something other than `NiceView`.

The appropriate type of the `handle` function in this code, given your stated goal, is

```
fun handle(command: Command): Reply<*>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the suggestion! This is spot on for what I need atm! :)

Comment: And one more thing: very well explained, thanks again @Louis!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the first issue, but the second one can be solved by simply adding [`in` modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) to the generic parameter of `Reply` class or return value of `handle` function:

```
interface View
data class NiceView(val name: String) : View

class Reply<in T : View>(view: T)

fun <T : View> handle(command: Command): Reply<T> {
    return Reply(NiceView(""))
}

// OR

class Reply<T : View>(view: T)

fun <T : View> handle(command: Command): Reply<in T> {
    return Reply(NiceView(""))
}
```

`in` modifier indicates **contravariance** (similar to "? super T" in Java).

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks! I oversimplified my example, because inside my `Reply` class I also have a function which takes a function of type `(T) -> String` (a serializer if you will) and that doesn't let me specify T as contravariant :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `handle()` is saying that `T` is a generic type that is a subclass of `View`. So `T` can be **any** subclass of `View`, but you are trying to force it to be `NiceView`. It means that code like this would not work:

```
val otherReply: Reply<OtherView> = handle(command)
```

`handle` is trying to return `NiceView`, but the generic parameter says it should be `OtherView`.

If you want to guarantee that your function always returns `Reply<T : View>`, you need to construct an instance of the generic type `T`. That means you have to identify the `View` implementation somehow. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but here's an example where it accepts the `view` as a parameter:

```
fun <T : View> handle(command: Command, view: T): Reply<T> {
    return Reply(view)
}

fun main() {
    val otherReply: Reply<OtherView> = handle(command, OtherView(""))
}
```

Or if you don't care about allowing the caller to specify the view type, you don't need the generic parameter at all:

```
fun handle(command: Command): Reply<View> {
    return Reply(NiceView(""))
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I would actually go for you second suggestion, but having oversimplified too much it didn't work for some reason in my case. I'm actually returning an `Either<Error, Reply<*>>` now. For some reason it would let me specify it as `Either<Error, Reply<View>>`